# Como verifico 2 tablas mysql a la vez?

Tags: php, mysql, html5

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `zzzz_1_post` WHERE POST_autor=1;
```

pero tambien quiero obtener

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `zzzz_0_post` WHERE POST_autor=0;
```

lo estoy haciendo en una while, pero no se como combinar las 2 tablas a la vez.

Mis tablas:

```
while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {//COMPROBAR POST
    $AMIGO_USUARIO_RED = $row['FRIEND_usuario'];
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM `zzzz_".$row['FRIEND_usuario']."_post` WHERE POST_autor=".$row['FRIEND_usuario'];
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if(!$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
        echo "La consulta falló ";
        echo "Error: Lo sentimos, error a al conectarse, reinicie la pagina.";
        echo "Query: " . $sql . "\n";
        echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->errno . "\n";
        echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error . "\n";
        exit;
    }

    while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {//MOSTRAR LOS POST
    ?>
        <article class="post_view_public">
          <div class="post_view_loading">
             <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
                <span class="sr-only">Cargando...</span>
          </div>
           <script type="text/javascript">
               function ocultar(){
                document.getElementById('post_view_loading').classList.add = "mostrar_loading_post" ;
                document.getElementById('post_view_public').classList.add = "ocultar_objetos";
                }
            </script>

            <div id="post_view_public">
            <div class="up">
            <?php
                    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `a_redcdark_social` WHERE id_usuarios=".$AMIGO_USUARIO_RED;
                    $resultado2 = $mysqli->query($sql2);
                    if(!$resultado2 = $mysqli->query($sql2)) {
                        echo "La consulta falló ";
                        echo "Error: Lo sentimos, error a al conectarse, reinicie la pagina.";
                        echo "Query: " . $sql . "\n";
                        echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->errno . "\n";
                        echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error . "\n";
                        exit;
                    }

                    // No hay datos en esa consulta
                    if ($resultado2->num_rows === 0) {
                        echo "No Tienes amigos agregadoss";
                    }

                     while($row2 = $resultado2->fetch_assoc()) {

                         ?>
                <a href="?page=profile&id=<?php echo $row2['id_usuarios'];?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $row2['RED_imagen_perfil'];?>" alt="user">
                    <h3><?php echo $row2['RED_nombre']; ?> <?php echo $row2['RED_apellido']; ?></h3>
                </a>

                <?php
                     }
                ?>
                <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="center" style="background:<?php echo $row['POST_background']?>">
        <?php

        if($row['POST_imagen'] == ""){
            echo $row['POST_texto'];
        }else{
            echo $row['POST_texto'];
            ?>

            <div class="imagen"><img src="<?php echo $row['POST_imagen'];?>" alt=""></div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
            </div>
            <div class="downcent">
               <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"> Like</i>
                <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="down">
                <img class="comentuser" src="images/example/myuser.jpg" alt=""><span class="info">Usuario</span>

                <input type="text" placeholder="Comenta esta publicación">

                <i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>
                <i>:v</i>
                <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
            </div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
               function mostrar(){
                    document.getElementById('post_view_loading').classList.remove = "mostrar_loading_post" ;
                   document.getElementById('post_view_loading').classList.add = "ocultar_objetos" ;
                   document.getElementById('post_view_public').classList.remove = "ocultar_objetos";
                    document.getElementById('post_view_public').classList.add = "mostrar_objetos";


                }
            </script>
        </article>
            <?php
    }

}//fin while 1
```

quiero que muestre las tablas de los usuarios(2)

Comment: Si quieres combinar las dos tablas, creo debes hacerlo con inner join.

Comment: AÑADE LA estructura de tus tablas de otro modo es dificil ayudarte

Comment: además edité tu pregunta ya que usaste la etiqueta html5 la cual en ningún momento es requerida para tu pregunta

Comment: ya puse mis tablas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lo unico que le puede ayudar es un inner join 
como en la siguiente sentencias

```
SELECT * FROM `zzzz_0_post` INNER JOIN zzzz_1_post
```

y en el codigo php en la vista tiene que colocar `zzzz_0_post.POST_autor  y zzzz_1_post.POST_autor`  para que imprima los dos datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: todo está en $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM a_redcdark_social WHERE id_usuarios=".$AMIGO_USUARIO_RED; $resultado2 = $mysqli->query($sql2); que puedo hacer para que detecte el id del post y que de ahi saga el usuario

Comment: solo devia poner $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `a_redcdark_social` WHERE id_usuarios=".$row['POST_autor'];

Answer (score 1):

En este caso quieres unir dos tablas que tienen los mismos campos, así que debes usar el comando SQL UNION, este une las tablas agregando una debajo de la otra


`SELECT * FROM zzzz_0_post UNION 
SELECT * FROM zzzz_1_post;`

Comment: pero se mezclan los cuadros y me muestra a un solo usuario, y no muestra el otro que puedo hacer?

Comment: todo está en$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `a_redcdark_social` WHERE id_usuarios=".$AMIGO_USUARIO_RED;
                    $resultado2 = $mysqli->query($sql2); que puedo hacer para que detecte el id del post y que de ahi saga el usuario

Comment: solo devia poner $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM a_redcdark_social WHERE id_usuarios=".$row['POST_autor'];